# How can I draw a view which is excluded from media projection?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-mediaprojection

I want to draw a view and exclude it from media projection.

I found some apps already have this behavior, so I think it is possible.
For example, when I share screen of android mobile phone to Samsung TV, floating button and control pannel is only drawn on mobile phone, not on TV.

I want to use media projection to capture screen, but I want to ignore some view. This view is a part of my app.

How can I draw a view or floating button excluded from media projection?